# What are the variables to train when training the last layer of inception_v4. (trainable_scopes/checkpoint_exclude_scopes)

Tags: python, deep-learning, classification, tensorflow2.0, pre-trained-model

I have used the following command to retrain the `inception_resnet_v2` model.

```
tcmd = "python train_image_classifier.py \
  --train_dir="+TRAIN_DIR+" \
  --dataset_name=training_images \
  --dataset_split_name=train \
  --dataset_dir="+DATASET_DIR+" \
  --model_name=inception_resnet_v2 \
  --checkpoint_path="+PRETRAINED_CHECKPOINT_DIR+"/inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt \
  --checkpoint_exclude_scopes=InceptionResnetV2/Logits,InceptionResnetV2/AuxLogits  \
  --trainable_scopes=InceptionResnetV2/Logits,InceptionResnetV2/AuxLogits  \
  --max_number_of_steps=1000 \
  --batch_size=16 \
  --learning_rate=0.01 \
  --learning_rate_decay_type=fixed \
  --save_interval_secs=60 \
  --save_summaries_secs=60 \
  --log_every_n_steps=100 \
  --weight_decay=0.00004"

os.system(tcmd)
```

Now I want to change the command to train the `inception_v4`. I have already downloaded the checkpoint for this model but I can’t figure out what are the `trainable_scopes` or `checkpoint_exclude_scopes` for retraining the last layer of this model.

Can some one please tell me what those are.

Comment: Try using InceptionV4/Logits,InceptionV4/AuxLogits. It should work when if you have the current model

Comment: i tried that already.. doesn't work for me

Comment: maybe your model is an older version. try this (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/inception_v4.py)

Comment: this one worked...thanks